# How to get differents backgrounds for each desktop working properly?

Tags: 10.10, compiz, desktop-background

I've followed all the instructions for getting differents wallpapers for each desktop. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. I've installed compiz-fusion-plugins-extra to add Wallpaper plugin on my Compiz Settings Manager (ccsm).

But unfortunaly I cannot get my wallpapers working properly. I follow these instructions http://ubuntuguide.net/different-wallpapers-on-each-workspace-in-ubuntu and I just get a black background.

Everything works fine after I press Win+P (I don't know what is this shortcut, refresh output I guess) or switch between ttf1 and ttf8 (ctrl+alt+f1 and ctrl+alt+f8). I tried reboot but the problem persist. What can I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: are you using binary drivers? probably that is the source of the weirdness.

Comment: no I'm not. I have two notebooks with the same problem.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `gconftool-2 --get /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop`?

Comment: gconftool-2 --get /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop
false

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the necessary image loading plugins are not enabled.

In the Image Loading category within CompizConfig Settings Manager, make sure the JPEG, Png, and/or Svg plugins are enabled to suit the types of images you are using for your wallpaper.

Comment: Hi. they are, how I've said after login I need to switch between tty1 and tty7 to get it working or press the super + P combination.